# I've created a Modal in React using Portal, but getting a blank space whenever I trigger the Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

FormModal.jsx

```
const Backdrop = (props) => {
  return <div className={styles.backdrop} onClick={props.onConfirm} />;
};

const ModalOverlay = (props) => {
  return (
    <Card className={styles.modal}>
      <header className={styles.header}>
        <p>
          Let's learn, share & inspire each other with our passion for computer
          engineering. Sign up now 
        </p>
      </header>

      <div className={styles.content}>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <h2>Sign In</h2>
            <LoginForm />
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <p>Don’t have an account yet? Create new for free!</p>
            <Image src={formImage} />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </Card>
  );
};

const FormModal = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <Backdrop onConfirm={props.onConfirm} />,
        document.getElementById("backdrop-root")
      )}

      {ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <ModalOverlay onConfirm={props.onConfirm} />,
        document.getElementById("overlay-root")
      )}
    </>
  );
};

const LoginForm = () => {
  return (
    <Form className="mt-4">
      <Form.Group className="" controlId="formBasicEmail">
        <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group className="mb-1" controlId="formBasicPassword">
        <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </Form.Group>

      <div className={`${styles.buttons} mt-4 d-flex flex-column`}>
        <Button size="sm" className="mb-5" type="submit">
          Sign In
        </Button>

        <Button size="sm" className="mb-2">
          {" "}
          <FaFacebookF /> Facebook
        </Button>
        <Button size="sm">
          <FcGoogle /> Google
        </Button>
      </div>
      <p className="font-weight-bold text-center mt-3">Forgot Password?</p>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default FormModal;
```

FormModal.module.css

```
.backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 100;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20vh;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

NavbarB.jsx *where I used the modal*
Just below the React Fragment, I've used the modal, but whenever I trigger that I am getting a blank space above Navbar. Here's a screenshot. I've used this type of Modal before and it worked fine, but here I'm using Bootstrap, so I think that might be causing the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
return (
    <>
     {showModal && (
       <FormModal onConfirm={closeHandler}/>
     )}
      <Navbar className={styles.navbar} expand="lg">
        <Container className="section-margin" fluid>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#">
            <Image src={Logo} />
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbarScroll" />
          <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-center" id="navbarScroll">
            <Form className={`${styles["search"]} justify-content-center`}>
              <button>
                <FaSearch />
              </button>
              <FormControl
                type="search"
                placeholder="Search"
                className="my-2"
                aria-label="Search"
              />
            </Form>
            <Nav
              className="justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3 mt-2"
              navbarScroll
            >
              <NavDropdown
                title="Create account. It's free!"
                id="navbarScrollingDropdown"
              >
                <NavDropdown.Item>Create new account</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item onClick={handleClick}>
                  or Login?
                </NavDropdown.Item>
              </NavDropdown>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't see any blank space.

Comment: I never understand why people are not using react-bootstrap to the full extent: There are already built Modal and Backdrop components in the library. Why are you using your own?

Comment: You, can see at the behind, just above the navbar, it's been pushed down.